# Handler and Runnable being slow

Tags: android, task, handler, runnable

I've fixed my problem but I think that my solution is not the best possible.

I want to have a timer that changes a text every second for a finite amount of time. I used a Handler and a Runnable to do so this way:

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    private Date timeSinceLastTask;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        remainingTime--;
        if(timeSinceLastTask != null){
            Date timeWokeUp = new Date();
            long hoursSinceSleep = timeWokeUp.getTime() - timeSinceLastTask.getTime();
            if(hoursSinceSleep > 2000){
                Log.e("Error", (int)(hoursSinceSleep/1000) + "sec");
                remainingTime - (int)(hoursSinceSleep/1000));
            }
        }
        Log.e("Tick", "Tack " + remainingTime);
        if(remainingTime > 0){
            updateText();
            timeSinceLastTask = new Date();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }else{
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
};
```

I had to add the part with the date to calculate when the last task was executed because sometimes, when the device went to sleep, i could take 50 seconds until the next one is executed and hence, slowing the countdown. One second cannot last more than one second!

With my fix, it's fine, but I was wondering what was the reason behind the task being executed slowly sometimes in sleep.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I have a reason for the downvote or an explanation why my question deserves one?

Comment: why don't you use a Timer instead?

Comment: What advantage would that have?

Comment: what API level is it run on? is it 6+?

Comment: Yes, API 15 and up

Answer (score 3):

When you use a `Handler`, it is bound to the thread where you created it. Which means, when you create this Handler inside your main thread(UI thread), then the runnable it executes must be running together with other UI tasks. It **may or may not** affect the performance of the main thread. This depends on what task you are running inside the runnable, and the performance of the UI as well.

On the other hand, if you would use a `Timer` instead, you are executing this task on a separate thread. It will not affect the main thread in any way. Plus, a `Timer` can be scheduled with delays before execution and period for each time of execution. It can be cancelled, it can be stopped, it can be continued. It is much flexible to manage and take control of a `Timer` than a `Handler` .

Comment: That's a nice answer, thank you! I'll take a look soon and keep you posted, thanks!